# I hit the permissions api and I want to decipher the Descriptor id

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to know, how to get an API URL which displays the 
`displayName` & `permissionDisplayString` values.

I want to know the details of Azure DevOps --> Project --> Project settings -->repositories --> Security for all Git repositories.

I am able to retrieve data of access control list by using the below API URL.
In the output I am able to find something like descriptor ID, will I be able to get my required details by deciphering that or do we have any other way through which I can get the required details.
Kindly let me know if we have any options apart from using F12 in google chrome.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=5.0
```

example:

```
"descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1",
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue discussed [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229624/identity-descriptor-security-api.html), the solution is to use this Rest API:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?descriptors={descriptor}&api-version=5.0
```

The `{descriptor}` is **with** the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;`.

In the response you get a property `providerDiaplyName`.

Comment: I am using the descriptor in the identity API that you gave me .
I need individual access control entries for each group under the security page. I want to get the complete information of access control summary page which displays the below options and its values. Kindly suggest me on how to retrieve the required information.

Options I need :

Bypass policies when completing pull requests
Create tag
Delete repository
Edit policies
Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags) Manage notes
Manage permissions